# District ou circonscription

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

Quand on parle des élections américaines à la chambre des représentants, en anglais on parle des *congressionnal districts* où sont élus chaque représentant. Faut-il le traduire par *district congressionnel* ou *circonscription congressionnelle* ou autre ?

Sur Wikipédia, c'est le bazar. Voir par exemple [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuxi%C3%A8me_district_congressionnel_de_Floride) (et quand on regarde l'historique, ça s'est crêpé le chignon à ce sujet, ça ne va pas être une source pertinente pour se décider)

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que tu peux dire les deux.

**District congressionnel** est la traduction littérale et semble être la forme la plus utilisée.

Néanmoins, on parle bien en français de **circonscription électorale** en français et non de district électoral, donc utiliser **circonscription congressionnelle** est aussi valide, [même si c'est une forme qui n'a l'air d'être utilisée que sur Wikipédia](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circonscription%20congressionnelle%22&sxsrf=ALeKk00LdWMVZqHA0v0LonrHIGcOJiwVRA:1595677462342&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjblcbiqejqAhVEAWMBHYvpBT0Q_AUoAXoECBAQCQ&biw=1920&bih=1137).

Voici le ngram:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Grouah remarque que "circonscription congressionnelle" n'est pas utilisé ailleurs, mais c'est parce que les françophone hors-wiki n'ont que très rarement besoin de **distinguer les circonscriptions fédérales de celle des états** (*congressional district* vs. *state electoral/legislative districts*). C'est pourquoi au Canada, où une situation similaire existe, on parle de circonscriptions fédérales ou provinciales.

En pratique, je suis d'accord avec Grouah que "circonscription électorale" employé seul est approprié si la distinction entre les circonscription des différents niveaux de gouvernement n'est pas nécessaire.

Si cette distinction est nécessaire, le problème est pratiquement insoluble, mais c'est plutôt parce qu'il n'y a aucune construction en français qui rende adéquatement le mot *state* employé en épithète dans ce sens. Cf. par exemple la traduction de *state road* dans les romans américains, où on fait face au même problème...